# Accessing tz database through PHP

Tags: php, timezone

I understand that PHP's timezone functionality makes use of the Olson tz database, and I was wondering whether there was a way to access the database information myself more directly, in order to get more accurate information through the use of longitudes and latitudes.

I guess, alternatively, if there are any good PHP libraries that can provide me with a timezone when given coordinates, that would be good too. I tried google's api for this, but it is limited and rejected every request I made to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only coordinates in the tzdb are in zone.tab, and are just a single latitude/longitude for each exemplar city.  That's good for displaying points on a map, but it isn't enough information to let you resolve an arbitrary lat/lon to a time zone.

If you're having issues with Google's apis, you can try to post about those specific issues or contact their support.  There are other providers as well, or you can build your own geospatial database to resolve them locally.

You should also review [the community wiki on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824) that I just started.

Comment: Thanks! I will check the stuff on the wiki.